# MatLab imfindcircles doesn't work in my bw image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I generate my bw image and labled it by using `bwlabel` in Matlab (attached image), and I want to use `imfindcircles` to find the circular objects in my bw image. But `imfindcircles` found no correct circle (on the white objects). Do somebody know why and how to fix it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: In what way does it not work - can you describe your error in more detail and post the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Irgb=imread('z:/ww5l8.jpg');
Igray=mean(double(Irgb)/255,3);
Ibw=Igray>0.5;

[centers,radii]=imfindcircles(Ibw,[6,80],'ObjectPolarity','bright');
fprintf('Found %d circles\n',size(centers,1));
figure(1); imshow(Ibw); hold on;
plot(centers(:,1),centers(:,2),'b*'); hold off;
```

A better option is to do filtering using region properties:

```
stats = regionprops(Ibw,{'Centroid','Eccentricity'})
Centroid=vertcat(stats.Centroid)
Eccentricity=vertcat(stats.Eccentricity)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask you what `Igray=mean(double(Irgb)/255,3);` mean?

Comment: This is a way to convert from rgb(3 planes)-uint8 (0-255) to gray(1 plane)-double (0-1). With uint8 you must be carefull when doing calculations. When you sum 2 uint8 numbers you will get max value of 255. and the average calculation will be wrong.

Comment: Ah Thanks! Then I don't understand. Why do we need to convert a black and white image to a gray image to find circles and it works better? I mean should the bw image better than the gray image, as its only 0 and 255?

Comment: I downloaded it in jpg form. and it was rgb.

Comment: Another fun thing to do: identify image components, edge-detect them, and do an actual circle fit on each one's edge. Ian Coope has a really nice algorithm for that last part.